# How to turn a string in an array into an expression?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am in the process of creating a math game and got stuck at this problem where I cannot convert the string in the randomly picked array (by `var randomProblem`) into an expression. The expressions need to stay as strings because I want to display the full expression on the screen for the user to answer. I tried to stringify the array that was picked by `var randomProblem`, then remove the quotation marks to turn it into an expression, but that didn't work.

With my current code, `var randomProblem` picks a random array from `var problems`. Then the contents of `var randomProblem` gets turned into a string by using `JSON.stringify()` and gets stored in a var called `processProblem`. Lastly, I logged the contents of `var processProblem` into the console and removed the double quotes to see what the outcome would be.

for example, if `randomProblem` chose `["6-18"]` as the random array and went through JSON.stringify and stripping of its quotes, the outcome would be `[16-8]` instead of `[8]`.

```js
(function playGame() {

  var problems = [
    ["6 * 6 - 27"],
    ["1 * 10 - 1"],
    ["2 + 5 * 1"],
    ["5 * 10 - 42"],
    ["8 + 6 - 7"],
    ["(1 - 1) * 20"],
    ["4 * 3 - 6"],
    ["98 - 95"],
    ["16 - 8"],
    ["(5 + 9) / 2"],
    ["(21 + 19) / 5"],
    ["(4 - 3) * 7"],
    ["(7 - 1) / 2"],
    ["(8 + 2) / 5"]
  ];

  //var problem = document.getElementById('problem');
  var randomProblem = problems[Math.floor(Math.random()*problems.length)];
  //var displayProblem = problem.innerHTML += randomProblem;
  var processProblem = JSON.stringify(randomProblem);

  console.log(processProblem.replace(/"/g, ""));

})();
```

Comment: Simple solution: eval, proper solution: parse the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work as you expect:

```
(function playGame() {

  var problems = [
    ["6 * 6 - 27"],
    ["1 * 10 - 1"],
    ["2 + 5 * 1"],
    ["5 * 10 - 42"],
    ["8 + 6 - 7"],
    ["(1 - 1) * 20"],
    ["4 * 3 - 6"],
    ["98 - 95"],
    ["16 - 8"],
    ["(5 + 9) / 2"],
    ["(21 + 19) / 5"],
    ["(4 - 3) * 7"],
    ["(7 - 1) / 2"],
    ["(8 + 2) / 5"]
  ];

  //var problem = document.getElementById('problem');
  var randomProblem = problems[Math.floor(Math.random()*problems.length)];
  //var displayProblem = problem.innerHTML += randomProblem;
  var processProblem = JSON.stringify(randomProblem).replace(/"/g, "");

console.log(processProblem);
console.log(eval(processProblem)[0]);

})();
```

I evaluate the content of your stringified `randomProblem` and take its first value (with index 0), because the evaluation result is an array